# Creating a custom Generator Hadoop InputFormat without input data

Tags: java, hadoop, testing

I'm trying to create an InputFormat that simply generates data without reading from an external location. It reads from the configuration for how much data to generate before closing. This is to help profile an OutputFormat in a non-test environment. Unfortunately, I cannot find any references on working with essentially a generator InputFormat.

The InputFormat I have so far is:

```
  public static class GeneratorInputFormat extends InputFormat<LongWritable, LongWritable> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, LongWritable> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return new GeneratorRecordReader();
    }

    @Override
    public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      long splitCount = job.getConfiguration().getLong(SPLITS_COUNT_KEY, 0);
      long splitSize = job.getConfiguration().getLong(SPLITS_SIZE_KEY, 0);
      List<InputSplit> splits = new ArrayList<InputSplit>();
      for (int i = 0; i < splitCount; i++) {
        splits.add(new TestInputSplit(splitSize));
      }
      return splits;
    }
  }

  public static class TestInputSplit extends InputSplit {

    private final long size;

    public TestInputSplit(long size) {
      this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLength() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getLocations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return new String[0];
    }
  }
```

The record reader simple spews numbers from 0 to the input length.

The error I'm getting is a missing file exception:

```
16/11/18 03:28:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1479265882561_0037
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.writeNewSplits(JobSplitWriter.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.createSplitFiles(JobSplitWriter.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at com.gmail.mooman219.cloud.hadoop.WordCountBench.main(WordCountBench.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunJarShim.main(HadoopRunJarShim.java:12)
16/11/18 03:28:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1479265882561_0037/job.split (inode 34186): File does $
ot exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_232487306_1 does not have any open files.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
```

I find this odd because at no point am I referencing any files on the input side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue of Hadoop trying to read non-existent files stems from the InputSplit. If the InputSplit doesn't define behavior for reading the data, then Hadoop defaults to it's own method.

This is solved by implementing Writable for the InputSplit. In my case the resulting InputSplit implementation ended up looking as such:

```
  public static class TestInputSplit extends InputSplit implements Writable {

    @Override
    public long getLength() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return 0L;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getLocations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {}

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that the file is not found

Comment: No files were being defined in the first place, it shouldn't be reading from anywhere.